# How to install Haskell module encoding-0.6.3 on windows?

Tags: encoding, haskell

My os is Windows 7, and with haskell platform 6.12

HaXml and other dependencies have already installed.

I tried to this after download:

```
runHaskell Setup.hs configure
```

and:

```
runHaskell Setup.hs configure 
--extra-include-dirs=F:/language/langer/haskell/encoding-0.6.3 
--extra-lib-dirs=F:/language/langer/haskell/encoding-0.6.3
```

and use cabal:

```
cabal install encoding
```

but all above print:

```
* Missing header file: system_encoding.h
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
```

i've tried these on Cygwin and MINGW and MSDOC, all failed.

**After googled a lot , i found [this](http://www.0x61.com/forum/programming-haskell-cafe-f245/building-encoding-on-windows-t1288727.html) 
(haskll-cafe and google-group have the same content)**

they mentioned the "langinfo.h", i found this file under cygwin "/usr/include" .
but still doesn't work.

**Anyone install encoding-0.6.3 successfully on windows ?**

Comment: In some version, the windows installer for Haskell had a bug and failed to put some c-headers in the right place. I googled and the Q'n'D-solution in this particular case was copying the directory `extralibs` in `$inst$\libs\ ` into `$inst$` (`$inst$` is where the Haskell platform was installed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to build it on Windows it's enough to pass -f-systemEncoding flag to cabal install

Answer (score 1):

I've had to post this as an answer to keep the formatting though it is really a comment, as I wouldn't follow these steps myself:

Potentially you can get "langinfo.h" installed on MinGW via the libgw32c library - there are some instructions on this page, but they look invasive and they aren't something I'd want to do myself (I like to keep MSYS as clean as possible):

http://placella.com/software/zenity/

Alternatively there is a patch here - but reading the comments this again seems invasive and isn't something I'd want to run (I like to keep my GHC installs as clean as possible):

http://dmwit.com/wyvern/encoding_ffi.dpatch